# Identify this cable!

Tags: power-supply, headphones

Found it at the office and I am curious about it. What is this cable used for?
Thanks.

It doesn't let me upload the image, so here is the link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzGRF.jpg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking for a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a pulse sensor to read one's pulse rate while exercising by the transmission of ultraviolet light or maybe infrared light through the skin to the receptor on the opposite side. It clips to one's fingertip. As blood flows through the smaller vessels, the light is alternately blocked and allowed to pass, providing appropriate data for the device into which it is connected.